# 'Module parse failed' error while lazy loading after react-scripts 3.0.0 update

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

I am lazy loading components in my React app, and it was working all fine. However, after the react-scripts 3.0.0 update, I keep getting the 'Module Parse failed: Unexpected token' error as follows:

```js
./src/routes/App.js 22:9
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (22:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import { Loader } from '../components/Preloaders/Loader';
| var ClippedDrawer = lazy(function () {
>   return import('../components/Drawer');
| });
| var Settings = lazy(function () {
```

Here is the beginning of the file App.js:

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react';
import {
    Router,
    Route,
    Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';

import { Loader } from '../components/Preloaders/Loader';

const ClippedDrawer = lazy(() => import('../components/Drawer'));
const Settings = lazy(() => import('../containers/Settings/Settings'));
const NotFound = lazy(() => import('../containers/NotFound'));
```

What is wrong with this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution: (But, please make a backup of your project in case it fails for you).

- Delete `node_modules`
- Delete `package-lock.json` (**NOT** `package.json`)

In the terminal:

- Run `npm install react-scripts@latest`
- Run `npm install`

Visit https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6673 for more details.